# WKT for local mine grid

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, well-known-text, affine-transformation

I have been trying to create a WKT entry to use in gdalwarp etc. I need an affine transform from coordinates in MGA94 Zone 54 to our local mine grid.  All efforts have so far failed, including using the bits and pieces I have found here.

I have a MapInfow.prj file entry that works beautifully but I need to convert our imagery from MGA to mine grid to supply to mining consultants. This entry is below with the affine parameters highlighted:

`"SRG/AISTR", 3008, 116,7, 141, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 10000000, 7,`**`0.999770876952, -0.031210618094, -193025.578125, 0.031224025413, 0.999768821523, -7589075.9140625`**`, -10000, -10000, 500000, 500000`

The standard scale, rotate parameters as supplied by our surveyors are here:

```
Rotation: 358.2111111 degrees
Scale: 0.999741893
Local East: 16000
Local North: 20000
MGAz54 E: 446231.629
MGAz54 N: 7596899.020
```

My latest attempt using the affine parameters from MapInfo are here:

```
FITTEDCS["SRG", 
   PARAM_MT["Affine",
       PARAMETER["num_row, 3], 
       PARAMETER["num_row, 3], 
       PARAMETER["elt_0_0", -193025.578125],
       PARAMETER["elt_0_1", -7589075.9140625], 
       PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 0.999770876952], 
       PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.031224025413], 
       PARAMETER["elt_2_0", -0.031210618094], 
       PARAMETER["elt_2_1", 0.999768821523], 
       PARAMETER["Central Meridian", 140.4800753], 
       PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin", -21.73061814]],  
   PROJCS["GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_54",
       GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["D_GDA_1994",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
       PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
       UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
   PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
   PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
   PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],
   PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",141.0],
   PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
   PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
   UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG",28354]]
```

As requested by Andre here are some control points:

> ```
> Local East    Local North MGAz54 East MGAz54 North
> 15896 27965   446376.2852 7604861.329
> 12458 28452   442956.0464 7605455.262
> 35698 27412   466146.2673 7603690.743
> 15698 29654   446231.1445 7606555.249
> 16547 23456   446886.0792 7600335.373
> ```

Comment: can you supply a few sample coords in both systems?

Comment: Sure thing...16444.297 27316.822 1384.4 446903.945 7604196.522
15896 27965  446376.285 7604861.329
12458 28452  442956.046 7605455.262
35698 27412  466146.267 7603690.743
15698 29654  446231.145 7606555.249
16547 23456  446886.079 7600335.373

Comment: Apologies for the formatting Andre.  The enter key didn't work as expected.

Comment: 16444.297, 27316.822 - 446903.945, 7604196.522
15896, 27965 - 446376.285, 7604861.329
12458,28452 - 442956.046, 7605455.262
35698, 27412 - 466146.267, 7603690.743
15698, 29654 - 446231.145, 7606555.249
16547, 23456 - 446886.079, 7600335.373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first try of mine:

```
+proj=omerc +lat_0=-21.73061814 +lonc=140.4800753 +alpha=-358.2111111 +k=0.9997418930000001 +x_0=16000 +y_0=20000 +gamma=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

using the parameters you gave, but not yet perfect.

For the Affine implementation, see also:

[PROJ.4 custom projection that is Transverse Mercator with Affine post-process](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49347/proj-4-custom-projection-that-is-transverse-mercator-with-affine-post-process)

GRASS `v.transform` should do the affine transformation, but I have not yet used it:

http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.transform.html

---

**EDIT**

an improved version, after doing some statistics:

```
+proj=omerc +lat_0=-21.906057 +lonc=140.31864 +alpha=2.04 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +gamma=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

or as WKT:

```
PROJCS["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center",
GEOGCS["GCS_GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)", 
  DATUM["D_unknown",
  SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
  UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center"],
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",-21.906057],
  PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",140.31864],
  PARAMETER["azimuth",2.04],
  PARAMETER["scale_factor",1], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
  PARAMETER["false_northing",0], 
  UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

which gives me less than 3 metres offset to the East for your most eastern point.

---

**Late Edit**

A better solution using gamma instead of alpha can be found here:

[Define custom CRS in WKT from point and angle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352168/define-custom-crs-in-wkt-from-point-and-angle)

Comment: Thanks Andre,  Just tried in gdalwarp and the resulting image was only about 4-5 metres east of true according when other data was overlaid.  I'll continue to refine based on your version.  Thanks a lot

Comment: You could apply a false Easting of +/- 5 meters, but that would spoil the GCP's you provided. Alternatively, try georeferemcing with some of your GCP to a vrt as an output. Then edit the vrt with a text editor, adding as much GCP as you want.

Comment: I had a good look at the original image and based on the GCP's it seems to be about 3.5 metres east of where it should be.  Therefore the reprojected image based on your parameters is pretty good.  I have since applied a false easting to both and the align well.  Thanks