# QGIS custom CRS from Mapinfo definition

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapinfo, affine-transformation

How do I define a custom CRS in QGIS from the Mapinfo grid definition below?

```
"MIM Grid",1008,33,7,139.48639389,-20.69008981, 1.000063,0,0,7,0.998796124,-0.049054077,12520.6,0.049054077,0.998796124,39952.907
For your information the Definition is:
Datum: Geocentric Datum of Australia (GDA94)
Projection: Universal Transverse Mercator
Central Meridian: 139.48639389 (decimal degrees) 139d 29’11.01802” E (degrees minutes seconds)
Origin Latitude: -20.69008981 (decimal degrees) 20d 41’24.32332” S (degrees minutes seconds)
Central Scale factor: 1.000063
Rotation Matrix: [ cos (theta)= 0.998796124 -sin (theta)=-0.049054077
sin (theta)= 0.049054077 cos (theta)= 0.998796124 ]
X offset: 12520.6
Y offset: 39952.907
```

I had a look at the QGIS documentation and PROJ4 but can't work out a way to input this information in a CRS definition in QGIS.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87213/wkt-for-local-mine-grid

Comment: Yes - definitely similar issue (local mine grid). I have also tried gdalsrsinfo to transform the .prj file to a proj4 but the "local" projection parameter creates an error... I have the feeling I need to build the whole proj4 string from scratch but there are so many parameters!

Comment: For a solution see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352168/define-custom-crs-in-wkt-from-point-and-angle

Comment: Thank you @AndreJ I will check it out.